# Is there a difference between the two?

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management, immutability

code A:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(10):
    lst+= ["42"]
```

code B:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(10):
    lst = lst + ["42"]
```

I know the output is the same, but is there a difference in the way the two lists are built?
What's happening in the back actually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
lst += ["42"]
```

You are mutating `lst` and appending "42" at the end of it. But when you say,

```
lst = lst + ["42"]
```

You are creating a new list with `lst` and `"42"` and assigning the reference of the new list to `lst`. Try this program to understand this better.

```
lst = ["1"]
print(id(lst))
lst += ["2"]
print(id(lst))
lst = lst + ["3"]
print(id(lst))
```

The first two ids will be the same, bu the last one will be different. Because, a new list is created and `lst` now points to that new list.

Not knowing the difference between these two will create a problem, when you pass a list as a parameter to a function and appending an item to it, inside the function like this

```
def mutate(myList):
    myList = myList + ["2"] # WRONG way of doing the mutation
tList = ["1"]
mutate(tList)
print(tList)
```

you will still get `['1']`, but if you really want to mutate `myList`, you could have done like this

```
def mutate(myList):
    myList += ["2"] # Or using append function
tList = ["1"]
mutate(tList)
print(tList)
```

will print `['1', '2']`

Comment: Do you happen to know whether the Python language definition *guarantees* that the id will change when you do `lst = lst + ["3"]`, or if that's left to the implementation? I ask because in principle a reference-counting implementation of Python might notice that `lst` has a refcount of 1 at the start of that operation and is being assigned back to its only referrer, and therefore as an optimization want to re-use the object. Of course it can re-use the underlying memory used for the array, but I wonder whether or not the language permits it to re-use the `list` itself too.

Comment: @SteveJessop As far as I know, implementation of `id` is python implementation dependent. But, in CPython, I know for sure that `id` will change when we do that operation. Because, in CPython, `id` returns the memory address of the object.

Comment: With the hypothetical optimization I describe above, the address of the new list would be the same as the old. So the reason the id changes on CPython isn't that CPython uses the address as the id, it's that it doesn't do the optimization. `id` must return different values for different objects, my question is whether a Python implementation is permitted to in effect give the new object the same address as the old object that is destroyed in the same statement (because its refcount hits 0).